# SVProgressHUD mask not changing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, singleton, svprogresshud

I have problem with maskType for SVProgressHUD. This HUD is working perfect for show and dismiss. My problem is when I call

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:(SVProgressHUDMaskType)SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    [SVProgressHUD show];
```

nothing happens. What could be the problem?

Comment: This is the code I've used in my projects and it works fine for me. `[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];` Also, you're calling show twice, both methods are a "show" method.

Comment: I tried that simple code too, but same thing, default mask is still loaded. For example, [SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor] is working pretty fine here, only mask not working.